# text.split not working for me in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm missing something obvious. Here is my script.rb:

```
print "Feed me words: "

text = puts gets.chomp
words = text.split(" ")     # <--- this is the line I am tossing the error

frequencies = Hash.new("0")
```

It throws the following error: `"undefined method`split' for nil:NilClass"`

Comment: Change `text = puts gets.chomp` to `text = gets.chomp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always find out what methods that you could use by doing

```
puts text.methods
```

This will give you an output of all methods that you could use with that particular object.
This is what I get in irb:

```
irb(main):004:0> text.methods
```

=> [:to_i, :to_f, :to_s, :to_a, :to_h, :inspect, :&, :|, :^, :nil?, :to_r, :rationalize, :to_c, :===, :=~, :!~, :eql?, :hash, :<=>, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :trust, :freeze, :frozen?, :methods, :singleton_methods, :protected_methods, :private_methods, :public_methods, :instance_variables, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set, :instance_variable_defined?, :remove_instance_variable, :instance_of?, :kind_of?, :is_a?, :tap, :send, :public_send, :respond_to?, :extend, :display, :method, :public_method, :define_singleton_method, :object_id, :to_enum, :enum_for, :==, :equal?, :!, :!=, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :**send**, :**id**]

As you can see split is not a part of that.. and that is the reason that you getting the error

> undefined method

Answer (score 0):

`puts` always returns `nil`. Obviously, you cannot split it.